# Assign bytes to Cython memory view

Tags: python, python-3.x, cython

I have a memory view of a 2-dimensional Cython array defined as

```
cdef unsigned char[:,:] store = view.array(
    shape=(n, 141),
    itemsize=sizeof(unsigned char),
    format="B",
)
```

, where `n` is the number of "rows" I have. For the sake of the example, lets assume `n=2`. Each row is a Python bytes object of size 141, which I have in a list of `bytes`:

```
rows = [
    b"4612edc38e7acc81520860b210c4ae7a14ace72bbb710514bd5ef71bb96e7af55b307580b015efac3cb84339fa9ff99401ed6fe211bb75b937fa575fc3928500c511aee084e5c",
    b"beb71c68b420fcb093d7c5894d726239bb0620229e46f91c11d3c2cd688e37c0c279ec844152cf87ea6c3f6915ac90aeb83ade44dfe22b1ae9c6fdd87e813eed98e5faca4d250",
]
```

I now want to move the data inside these rows into the memory view. At the moment, I'm doing this in a rather stupid way:

```
for i, row in enumerate(rows):
    for j, byte_ in enumerate(row):
        store[i, j] = byte_
```

While this works, I assume it is inefficient (unless `cythonize` does some magic to get rid of the loops), and it just looks messy and overly complicated. I want to be able to simply do something like:

```
store[:,:] = rows
```

or, at least:

```
for i, row in enumerate(rows):
    store[i, :] = row # fails with TypeError: an integer is required
```

---

Sadly, none of that works. I also tried the following:

```
# fails because the resulting number is a bigint (?)
store[i, :] = int.from_bytes(bytearray, sys.byteorder)
# fails with TypeError: an integer is required
store[i, :] = np.array(list(row))
```

---

There must be a better way. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following works:

```
cdef const unsigned char[::1] row

for i, row in enumerate(rows):
    store[i, :] = row
```

Essentially it can only do a sliced "element-by-element" copy if it knows that row is a memoryview. Otherwise it assumes that row is a single value that the slice should be filled with.

I've used `const unsigned char[::1]` since bytes objects are immutible and contiguous. Without the `const` it won't compile, while the `::1` just makes it a little more efficient.

Comment: Thanks, that is certainly an improvement.